# Tkinter: simple dialog box appears behind main root page on raspberry pi

Tags: tkinter, raspberry-pi, window-managers, simpledialog

I've spent forever looking for a solution to this. There are tons of posts on stackoverflow about this problem, which have gotten me this far and now I am stumped where to go next. I need to use the dock attribute on root because it needs to appear above all other windows, and without the bar at the top. The splash attribute almost works, but then other windows can pop up on top of it too when clicking on the screen where their borders are behind the app. For some reason the code below *does not work on a raspberry pi*, the simpledialog box appears behind the root application, so you cannot see it at all.

However, *it works on my linux laptop*. The only thing I could think of is that it is a window manager issue. From following the advice of more posts, I looked at the file "/etc/X11/default-display-manager", my raspberry pi is running default raspbian which utilizes the lightdm manager and my laptop uses gdm3. With some more research it seems raspberry pis can struggle to run gdm3. I tried downloading GNOME (which I think is gdm3) by running "sudo tasksel" in the command window and it still ran into the same problem. At this point I'm willing to try pretty much anything.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog, messagebox
Root = tk.Tk()
Root.attributes('-type', 'dock')
width = Root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = Root.winfo_screenheight() - 30
Root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (width, height))
button = tk.Button(Root, text="exit", command=Root.destroy).pack(pady=20)
Root.deiconify()
Root.lift()
Root.focus_force()
J = tk.simpledialog.askfloat("Input", "Number of points per scan:",parent=Root,minvalue=1000, maxvalue=7000)
Root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the attribute `-topmost` witch just puts a window on top always (unless there are multiple windows on `topmost`), window manager have two kinds of [`z-axis`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#z-order), the layers overlap by level and the layer items overlap by focus history.

```py
import tkinter as tk

class App_Dialog(tk.Tk):

    def dial_return(self):
        self.callback(
            self.entry.get()
        )

    def __init__(self, text, callback, master):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        mw, mh = master.winfo_width(), master.winfo_height()
        self.geometry('300x200+{0}+{1}'.format(
            (mw // 2) - 150, (mh // 2) - 100
        ))
        self.attributes('-topmost', True)
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.config(bg='#A0A0A0')
        self.callback = callback
        self.update()

        tk.Label(self, text=text).pack(anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER)
        tk.Button(
            self, text='Save', command=self.dial_return
        ).pack(anchor=tk.CENTER)


class App(tk.Tk):

    def dialog_callback(self, text):
        self.list.insert(0, text)
        self._dialog.destroy()
        self._dialog = None

    def dialog(self, text, callback):
        if self._dialog is None:
            self._dialog = App_Dialog(
                text, callback, self
            )

    def quit(self):
        if self._dialog is not None:
            self._dialog.quit()
        self.tk.quit()

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.state('zoomed')

        self.list = tk.Listbox()
        self._dialog = None

        self.b_top = tk.Button(
            self, text='tk::top',
            command=lambda: self.dialog(
                'Fill this:', self.dialog_callback
            )
        )
        self.b_quit = tk.Button(
            self, text='Close',
            command=lambda: self.quit()
        )
        self.b_top.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.b_quit.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.list.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: This works except there is still the tkinter title bar at the top with the minimize, maximize, close buttons. Is there a way to remove that bar and use topmost?

Comment: Not sure how to edit comments otherwise I would just edit the last one. Overrideredirect makes the app in front of the dialog box again and the fullscreen attribute makes it appear in front of my florence keyboard. I guess fullscreen overrides topmost.

Comment: You can make it a border less window instead of full-screen but the example works as expected on windows, i don't know why wouldn't work on linux

Comment: I've actually done a fair amount of research on the attributes. I believe that windows has separate functionality for many of the attributes, Overrideredirect used to not be supported at all on linux. Even my example code works great on a linux laptop (and most likely on windows too). I think its because they use different window managers.

Comment: Don't be surprised if it turns out that is a tkinter "bug," it is designed to be simple, if you need to make a complex app use something else, i use wxWidgets, it's a good replacement on python.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense... I have heard before not to use python for GUIs, my app just keeps getting more complex and it seems it has outgrown tkinters capabilities. Thanks for the help!